# How to calculate the difference between consecutive rows in spark dataframe

Tags: sql, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

*I have a DataFrame with the following structure, whenever **ch_status** is zero then I need to calculate the difference between the corresponding rows in the **TEMPERATURE** column and need to show in the new column as **diff** for each **ID***

The expected result would be:

[image]

*Can you please help me with how can I do that?*

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Amira Bedhiafi
I have tried with window functions but didn't get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a gaps and islands approach and find the consecutive runs. This alternate method is straightforward though:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        lag(ch_status) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as last_status,
        lag(temperature) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as last_temperature
    from T
)
select id, sum(temperature - last_temperature) as diff
from data
where ch_status = 0 and last_status = 0
group by id;
```

This will work regardless of whether the sequence is monotonic (always ascending) or not.